How to prevent image loading after it's already loaded in dom in react
enter image description here
these images are already cached by the browser and also we have implemented caching of the image URL in indexdb.
in order to improve the user experience we are facing an image flickering issue on the listing page of our react project.
is there any solution to this image flickering issue
expectation:- if image is already loaded the image should be immediately rendered on dom instead of after loading

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
